# Submit AlertDialog fields OnMapLongClick using json throwing NullPointerException

Tags: php, android, json, maps

When Long Press on GoogleMAPv2, shows AlertDialogBuilder with edit fields where submit using Json object throwing null Pointer Exception, i have checked the connectivity and it is right(submit html giving correct response from Backend PHP and in mysql).
I have no clue whats wrong with java code, please help.

public class Map extends Activity implements OnMapClickListener,
        OnMapLongClickListener, QueryInterface {
    final Context context = this;

```
final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
private GoogleMap myMap;
SQLiteDatabase sql;
Cursor c;
String EName,ECompany,EDesc,ELatlong,EPhone,EEmail;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String ADD_URL = weburl+"/addent.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment) myFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

    myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

    sql = openOrCreateDatabase(db_name, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    c = sql.query("etable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        String latlong = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("latlong"));
        String CompanyName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Company"));
        String[] parts = latlong.split(",");
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]); // 004
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);

        // LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(13.0839, 80.2700);
        LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(
                newLatLng).title(CompanyName);
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newLatLng));
        myMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();
    sql.close();

}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng point) {

    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.adde, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final EditText EntName = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.editEntName);
    final EditText EntOrganisation = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.editEntCompany);
    final EditText EntDesc = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.editEntDesc);
    final EditText EntEmail = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.editEntEmail);
    final EditText EntPhone = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.editEntPhone);

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            EName = EntName.getText().toString();
            EDesc = EntDesc.getText().toString();

            myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(
                    EntOrganisation.getText().toString()));
            sql = openOrCreateDatabase(db_name, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("EName", EntName.getText().toString());
            cv.put("Company", EntOrganisation.getText().toString());
            cv.put("Description", EntDesc.getText().toString());
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(point
                    .toString(), "(");
            String one = "";
            while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                one = st.nextElement().toString();
                }
            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(one, ")");
            String two = "";
            while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
                two = st2.nextElement().toString();
                break;
                }
            ELatlong =two;
            EEmail = EntEmail.getText().toString();
            EPhone = EntPhone.getText().toString();
            cv.put("latlong", two);
            cv.put("Email", EntEmail.getText().toString());
            cv.put("Phone", EntPhone.getText().toString());
            //Online Sync
            new PushList().execute();
            long success = sql.insert("etable", null, cv);
            if (success > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(Map.this, "Added Successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
        Toast.makeText(Map.this,
                "Problem in adding etable please try again later.",
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }
        }
    )

    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
    }
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                RQS_GooglePlayServices);
    }
}
class PushList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    boolean failure = false;
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entName",EName));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entCompany", ECompany));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entDesc", EDesc));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entlatlong", ELatlong));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entPhone", EPhone));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entEmail", EEmail));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            //Posting user data to script 
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    ADD_URL, "POST", params);
            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Entreprenure Added!", json.toString());
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Adding  Failed!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
            }
    }
}
```

Logcat follows,

```
03-28 13:46:40.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 13:46:40.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6647): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 13:46:40.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at com.android.fund.SupportMapFragmentActivity$1.onClick(SupportMapFragmentActivity.java:132)
03-28 13:46:40.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
03-28 13:46:40.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 13:46:40.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-28 13:46:40.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-28 13:46:40.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 13:46:40.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-28 13:46:40.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-28 13:46:40.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-28 13:46:40.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Add the LogCat output for the NullPointerException so we can see what line is throwing it.

Comment: i doubt on alert Dialog button..

Comment: You're trying to call a method on a null object at line 132, but we can't see where that is if you don't specify it in the question.